# Html.DropDownListFor will not select value into property

Tags: html

I've spent some time looking through Stack Overflow for someone with the same exact issue as mine. My Html.DropDownListFor in view, will not select value into property. It looks correct to me, but I am new at this. Any suggestions would be greatly appreciated. Thank you,Ken

```
public class SelectUserModel
{
public SelectUserModel()
{
    this.users = new List<string>();
}
public List<string> users { get; set; }
public string UserName { get; set; }
}

Controller
[HttpGet]
public ActionResult SelectUser()
{
    SelectUserModel selectUserModel = new SelectUserModel();
    var userNames = selectUserModel.users;
  if (User.IsInRole("Admin"))
  {
    var reader = Connection.ExecuteReader("select distinct username from users");
    while (reader.Read())
    {
       userNames.Add(reader["username"].ToSafeString());
    }
    else
    {
       userNames.Add(User.GetUserId());
    }
    return View(selectUserModel);
}
View
@model xxxx.Web.Models.SelectUserModel
...
@{
var MySelectList = new List<SelectListItem>();
foreach (var user in Model.users)
{
    MySelectList.Add(new SelectListItem
    {
        Value = user,
        Text = user
     });
}
}
@using (Html.BeginForm())
{
    <div class="col-md-8">
        @if (User.IsInRole("Admin"))
        {
          @Html.DropDownListFor(model => model.UserName, new 
          SelectList(MySelectList.GroupBy(o => o.Value).Select(c => 
          c.FirstOrDefault()), "Value", "Text"), new { @class = "form-control" })

          @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.UserName, "", new { 
`@class = "text-danger" })
...
Html looking at page source
<form action="/Manager/SelectUser" method="post"> -- not sure why this `
shows post?


<div class="col-md-8">
<select class="form-control" id="UserName" name="UserName"><option 
value="administrator">administrator</option>
...
</select><span class="field-validation-valid text-danger" data-valmsg- 
for="UserName" data-valmsg-replace="true"></span>                        
</div>
</form>
```

Comment: Hey there, welcome to [so]. To format your code as a block, select all your code first and then click 'code'. Or you can add 4 spaces before each line.